# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main PID: 19302 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

I'm trying to create a login and registration auth with *Firebase*, but when i try to running the app by usb debugging it won't start and keep crashing like there's problem in my *AndroidManifest xml*.

Here is the *Log Run* :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.firebase.loginauth, PID: 19696
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firebase.loginauth/com.firebase.loginauth.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.firebase.loginauth-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.firebase.loginauth.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19696 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Here is xml for my *AndroidManifest*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.firebase.loginauth" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And then this is an example of my *activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Instead of

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Answer (score 0):

in your log it shows that the code is not able to inflate AppBarLayout Class

```
# Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

so its probably a dependency problem, in root CoordinatorLayout element i see that you are using AndroidX so try to use proper dependency for AppBarLayout

try to use :

```
com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

instead of

```
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

and for your Toolbar use :

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

instead of

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

P.S : you can see full guideline in official document in below link :
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#class_mappings

Comment: @lhmrnfrzrfr if that answer helped you, i would appreciate upvote :),thanks